# How can I access Windows COM objects in R v3?

Tags: r, com

Some time ago, you used to be able to install the [`rcom` package in R to use COM scripting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14862861/is-it-possible-call-a-com-object-from-within-r-if-the-com-object-is-exposed-fro) (eg, access to external programs.)  Unfortunately, it [seems to be discontinued](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rcom/index.html):

> Package ‘rcom’ was removed from the CRAN repository.
>
> Formerly available versions can be obtained from the archive.
>
> This depends on statconnDCOM, which nowadays restricts use, contrary
>   to the CRAN policy for a package with a FOSS licence. See
>   http://rcom.univie.ac.at/ and http://www.statconn.com/.

Following the archive and statconn links and installing one of the older versions in R version 3 gives the error:

> “Error: package ‘rcom’ was built before R 3.0.0: please re-install
>   it”.

I am not very familiar with R, but there seems no way around this message - after all, it occurs when installing, so re-installing doesn't seem to be the answer. It appears as though `rcom` is simply not available for recent (3.0+) versions of R.  I have also scanned the [package list](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/available_packages_by_name.html), although searching for "COM" there returns over a hundred results and it is possible I missed the right one when clicking through them.

**How can I use the `rcom` package, or use COM from within R some other way?**

(Note: I am asking this question on behalf of a colleague.  I have no experience with R myself at all. Both of us, when searching for answers, could not find anything. I am sure that others are also using COM in the latest version of R, though!)

Comment: Do the answers to this question help.... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16651837/rexcel-in-r-3-0-x

Comment: I have tried RDCOMCLient, which does exactly this: http://www.omegahat.org/RDCOMClient/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I looked at the rcom source code a few months ago. It seems I can get it to build and install OK on R3.0.1. Below is the procedure if it helps.

- Get a checkout of the latest source code of rcom. I have rcom_2.2-5.tar.gz locally. I can google something at the following address, but I have no idea of the provenance, so up to you to check it is legit. http://cran.open-source-solution.org/web/packages/rcom/index.html
- in R do `install.packages('rscproxy')`
- install Rtools as per the instructions on the R web site (http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools),
- open a Windows command prompt i.e. run "CMD"
- go to the folder containing the 'rcom' folder, and at the command prompt:

  ```
  set R="c:\Program Files\R\R-3.0.1\bin\i386\R.exe"
  %R% CMD check --no-manual rcom
  ```
- check it passes without too many complaints. Your call as to the --no-manual option (if you have MiKTeX installed you may remove it)

  ```
  %R% CMD INSTALL rcom
  ```

should result in

```
    installing to c:/Rlib/rcom/libs/i386
    ** R
    ** inst
    ** preparing package for lazy loading
    ** help
    *** installing help indices
    ** building package indices
    ** testing if installed package can be loaded
    rcom requires a current version of statconnDCOM installed.
    To install statconnDCOM type
         installstatconnDCOM()
    This will download and install the current version of statconnDCOM
    You will need a working Internet connection
    because installation needs to download a file.
    * DONE (rcom)
```

- in R:

  ```
  library(rcom)
  installstatconnDCOM()
  ```
- I tried a `comRegisterRegistry() ; comRegisterServer()
  ; x<-comGetObject("Excel.Application")` but I get a NULL for `x`. I am not a user of rcom so while it all seems to compile fine; it may just not work anymore.

If you happen to need to access .NET code, a viable option (and yes I have a vested interest in mentioning it) may be the [rClr](http://r2clr.codeplex.com) package.

Hope this helps; I'd be interested to hear how you go.

Comment: +1 for rClr, it works just beautifully (I was up and running in about 2 minutes). I never really got rcom to work, and not for lack of trying.

Answer (score 5):

This really should be a comment, but I don't have enough rep points yet to leave one.
I found that the above steps did not work for me, but the answer posted by Lisa Ann on this question, [RExcel in R 3.0.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16651837/rexcel-in-r-3-0-x?lq=1), did solve my problem installing rcom. Since you need rcom to run RExcel, the initial steps to install RExcel cover installing rcom on newer versions of R (such as 3.0.2).

Specifically, following the advice on statconn's wiki, http://homepage.univie.ac.at/erich.neuwirth/php/rcomwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:how_to_install

> You also need to follow these instructions if you upgrade R, i.e. you install a new >release of R after you have installed RExcel.
>
> Download the statconn DCOM server and execute the program you downloaded
>   Start R as administrator (on Windows 7 you need to right-click the R icon and click the >corresponding item)
>   In R, run the following commands (you must start R as administrator to do this)
>
> > > > install.packages(c("rscproxy","rcom"),repos="http://rcom.univie.ac.at/download",lib=.Library)
> > > >
> > > > library(rcom)
> > > >
> > > > comRegisterRegistry()
>
> Now you have rcom installed, [instructions for installing RExcel follow...]

Comment: Thanks. Gave you an upvote, hope that helps your rep! Btw I think it's fine as an answer; it does answer the question.

Answer (score 2):

New versions of rcom and rscproxy (also for current versions of R) are available from a different repository. Just use http://rcom.univie.ac.at/download as the R repository to install from and you can download and install binary versions of statconn packages from there.

Hope this helps!