# Install package in R

Tags: r, package

I am trying to install rscproxy and rcom packages on windows. I tried the following methods:

**Method 1:**

Opening R as administrator and using this command

```
>install.packages(c("rscproxy","rcom"),repos="http://rcom.univie.ac.at/download",lib=.Library)
```

But getting error as unable to access the url.

**Method 2:**

Downloaded the zip of the packages from cran and using this command

```
>install.packages('D:\\rscproxy_2.0-5.zip', lib='C:\\Program Files\\R\\R-3.1.1\\library',repos = NULL)
package ‘rscproxy’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
> install.packages('D:\\rcom_2.2-5.zip', lib='C:\\Program Files\\R\\R-3.1.1\\library',repos = NULL)
package ‘rcom’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
```

But then:

```
> library(rcom)
Error: package ‘rcom’ was built before R 3.0.0: please re-install it
```

I also referred these [How do I install an R package from source?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1474081/how-do-i-install-an-r-package-from-source) and [Manually Downloading and Installing Packages in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14806705/manually-downloading-and-installing-packages-in-r) but all in vain.

Please help me with any fix for this.

**P.S : I am using R 3.1.1 on 32-bit Windows 7**

Comment: From their download.html page:" CRAN is not hosting some of the components of our software any more. RAndFriends depended on these componetes to be available on CRAN. Therefore, to use our tools, R has to be installed manually. Our Wiki has < a href="http://homepage.univie.ac.at/erich.neuwirth/php/rcomwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:how_to_install>" So did you follow the instuctions on that page to create an "upgraded" version of R?

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18651218/3297280) might help

Comment: @BondedDust Yes I already followed their instruction(see method 1 above) but getting error.

Comment: @Ujjwal with your link I am now able to install rscproxy. But still cannot install rcom